# What are difference between Timeout, Response time and Latency time when request an Api?

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, latency

I have a issues when request an api: when ai request API because the delay of networking then I must waiting the data response is slowly and i must calculator the time request between difference period time to setting the time for function authoring on API(base on period time of client). But I'm not clear about **Timeout**, **Response time** and **Latency time** to create a best report as bellow: 
[image: latency report]

Please help to clearly. Thank you very much !